# Which Linux OS should i use?

Tags: boot

i have windows 8.1 currently and i want to switch to Ubuntu especially or any Linux OS would be fine and my computer specs are as below:

```
Processor:Intel(R)Pentium(R)D CPU 2.66GHz 2.67GHz
RAM: 1.25GB
System Type: 32bit Operating System, X64 Based Processor
```

my PC is very old and as i am school student i dont need a PC better than this still i finish my schooling. Please suggest me a Linux OS,

I dont need Linux for gaming purpose but just for my programming place as such.

Thanks

Comment: u definitely  need [lubuntu](http://lubuntu.me)

Comment: Bro But on the same system windows 8.1 works perfectly then why not Ubuntu?

Comment: despite the **l** in lubuntu, it would run very very fast and at the same time still do everything ubuntu, kubuntu and the rest can do. I don't know much about windows but considering the specs if you need performance over desktop beauty go for lubuntu

Comment: Oh! So the latest lubuntu will work fine?

Comment: yh. get the lubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 5):

Given the low specifications of your machine, I'd recommend you a lightweight Linux distribution. If you would like to get something ready to run out of the box, take a look at [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.net/) or [Debian](https://www.debian.org/). Alternatively, you could use a distribution such as [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/) and install only the components that you require, thus building a system tailored to your needs. You could read through [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions) to get a full list of Linux distributions and find the one suitable for you depending on your requirements and experience.

Comment: But windows 8.1 works perfectly fine on that system! then why not Ubuntu?